# jwt.encode fails with "Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable"

Tags: python, django, jwt, token, access-token

I am trying to return a token to my user after they have been successfully logged in but keep getting the following error:

`TypeError: Object of type 'bytes' is not JSON serializable`

How can I fix it? This is my code so far:

```
   if user:
        selected_user = {
            'email': user.__dict__['email'],
            'password': user.__dict__['password'],
            'account_type': user.__dict__['account_type'],
            'token': ''
        }

        if bcrypt.checkpw(request.data['password'].encode('utf8'), selected_user['password'].encode('utf8')):
            payload = {
                'email': selected_user.email,
                'account_type': selected_user.account_type
            }
            selected_user['token'] = jwt.encode(payload, "SECRET_KEY")
            response_details = {
                'data': selected_user,
                'message': 'Login successful.',
                'code': '200',
                'status': HTTP_200_OK
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
        else:
            response_details = {
                'message': "Invalid password.",
                'code': "400",
                'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
            }
            return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
    else:
        response_details = {
            'message': "Invalid email and password combination.",
            'code': "400",
            'status': HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST
        }
        return Response(response_details, status=response_details['status'])
```

Comment: Can you copy-paste the error message verbatim in the question?

Comment: This is the model it's based on: https://pastebin.com/wGZBzAUN. None of which are of type `bytes`.

Comment: Here is the error message: https://pastebin.com/kjCzMYcP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try importing json, and on your return use json.dumps(response_details):

```
 return Response(json.dumps(response_details), status=response_details['status'])
```

Comment: It doesn't get to this point in the code, on the client side I get `500 (Internal Server Error)`.

Comment: This error will indeed throw an internal server error, even if it occurs on the return method

Answer (score 2):

In **older versions** of PyJWT like 1.7 **decode** is required at the end:

```py
jwt.encode(payload, "SECRET_KEY", algorithm='HS256').decode('utf-8')
```

If you are using the **recent versions like 2.3.1 it is not necessary to dump or decode**, a string will be generated already in UTF-8

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, solved the problem using PyJWT version 1.6.1